# teleop turtlebot

Tags: turtlebot, teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey everybody:
I want to build a node to use keyboard or ps3 handshacker to control my turtlebot ( useing C++ or python )means use this node to send twist message to cmd_vel , cuz i think there must be someone done this thing already , so I'd like to ask if someone has code? and could you pass it to me ?

ps : I'm using ros INDIGO and i want to build a node to using keyboard to congtrol my turtlebot , also i want to learn the code , does anyone have **turtle_teleop_key.cpp** in INDIGO vision?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198801/teleop-turtlebot/) by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-10**:
hello everyone i found that hydro teleop_key.cpp could use in indigo...............

**Comment by [Ahyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19943/ahyan/) on 2015-01-07**:
"--i want to build a node to using keyboard to control my turtlebot , also i want to learn the code , does anyone have turtle_teleop_key.cpp in INDIGO vision?"

Me too. From where I can collect hydro version of turtlebot_key.cpp? Can anybody help?

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-07**:
@Ahyan i just use the turtlesim_teleop node in  ROS WIKI tutorials ,and modify the "turtle vel/cmd" to "vel cmd" in its code , then it work well   - -|||

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already a teleop package for the turtlebot called [turtlebot_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_teleop). You can use the tutorials to use the keyboard to teleoperate your turtlebot. Also there are tutorials for using joysticks, ps3 joystics and xbox360 game controller to teleop your robot.

To use the keyboard, open a new terminal and type

```
roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch
```

The launch file is easy to understand.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2014-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2014-12-03**:
@ankitravankar   thx